# Is there any kind of feed (rss|atom|...) that we can use?

Tags: support, questions, rss

Is there any kind of feed just to receive new questions comfortably in our feed readers?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, almost every page has an RSS feed -- check for the icon at the bottom of the page or the html `<meta>` tags in the header.

Comment: What about "unanswered"? I'm assuming that's a policy not to have an rss for that feed?

Answer (score 0):

if you open this site on firefox it will show u an RSS icon in address bar so that you can subscribe to feed using single click